# VBOs or Display Lists - GPU compatibility

Tags: c#, opengl, compatibility, opentk

I'm working on a new OpenGL application, and am aware that display lists will be deprecated in OpenGL 3.1 (along with many other useful features, which (to me) seems kind of silly) and replaced with Vertex Buffer Objects. I successfully drew a triangle using VBOs on an NVidia card, but the example failed to run on an Intel chip on my netbook, because it does not support glGenBuffers. It seems there is a crucial flaw here in OpenGL (a compatibility breakage between newer and older GPUs/GMAs). As a small business, compatibility with as many systems as possible is necessary for my game, but I don't want my program to not work on newer graphics cards (due to its dependency on display lists, which have been removed from the OpenGL 4.1 specification). Which would give me the widest support on graphics cards (old AND new). Display lists, or vertex buffer objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application will run on GMA, you necessarily have a low poly count.  So the inefficiency of having display lists emulated in the drivers for new video cards will not be a problem, they have bandwidth to spare.

If you're still concerned about efficiency, make sure to use `glVertexPointer`/`glDrawArray` to maximize batch size.  This can be combined with display lists, but reduces the number of separate operations in the list and therefore makes emulation less problematic.

Worst case, if some platform really doesn't support display lists, you can replace `glCallList` with a function call.

Comment: Are they emulated in the drivers, removed altogether from the GPU (including drivers), or is it necessary to use a 'compatibility context' to get it to work on the GPU?

Comment: @IDWMaster: Supported in drivers when you request a compatibility context (or an old version of OpenGL, if you support GMA you must be using 1.5 or so anyway).  Whether it's 100% emulation or partly hardware accelerated depends on the chip, but in any case it should keep up with any geometry Intel GMA can handle.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of the glDrawArray function! This should definitely improve performance! I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: @IDWMaster: `glDrawArray` (or `glDrawElements`) is part of VBOs as well.  Originally you passed in system memory pointers to `glVertexPointer`, with VBOs you pass in a GPU memory pointer.  But the overall structure of the code is the same.  And with or without VBO, it provides a significant performance advantage over `glBegin`/`glEnd`.

Comment: @Ben: "if you support GMA you must be using 1.5 or so"  Aren't you optimistic! :)

Comment: @genpfault: Sorry, version 1.4 is the highest supported by the pervasive GMA900 and GMA950 families.

Answer (score 3):

Your Intel card *does* support VBOs but only through the ARB interfaces.  Try `glGenBuffersARB` (along with converting all your other VBO code to use the ARB versions).  It will work on nVidia and Intel GMA.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to the ARB interface vs the standard one? Why are there two different ways to draw VBOs?

Comment: The ARB interfaces were from the proposal to add a new feature (the Architecture Review Board) and represent the interfaces before they were finalized.  In a given driver (which supports both) usually the ARB and regular interfaces will be nearly identical in behavior (assuming the spec didn't change much when the proposal was adopted).

Comment: @IDWMaster: Most OpenGL features start out as vendor extensions, then become ARB-approved extensions, then finally are added to a future release of the core spec.  This prevents the core spec from getting cluttered with failed features.  There's no backward compatibility requirements on extensions, whereas functions accepted into the core stick around forever (at least in the compatibility profile).

Comment: @IDWMaster: The only actual disadvantage in this particular case is that you have to check `GL_EXTENSIONS` for the extension's name (before loading function pointers), and you have to type 3 more characters per function and constant (though, you _could_ even use the non-ARB names). That's because this particular extension is 100% identical to the core functionality, only the symbol names are different. Everything else, including constants, is the same (that is **not** true for every extension).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can query for the OpenGL version supported the system and use DisplayLists or VBO's accordingly instead of relying on one method to be compatible with every OpenGL version. This way you can be certain that you are using the most up-to-date, most efficient and fastest way of drawing, whatever method (displaylists/VBO's) is supported by the system.

Also, such an implementation can be easily extended to support future drawing methods in, say, OpenGL 4.4 or OpenGL 5.0.
However, this can result in multiple pieces of code doing, functionally, the same thing: tell the GPU what to do which might increase code-size and complexity.